# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException On first call of the rest Service

Tags: java, json, jboss, jersey

Hello I am trying to develop rest application for jboss 6.3 using [Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio](http://www.jboss.org/products/devstudio/overview/)

I have very strange issue: When i access my rest service first time via fiddller i get following exception:

```
15:49:18,053 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/OASExtention-war].[javax.ws.rs.core.Application]] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet javax.ws.rs.core.Application threw exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.xc.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector from [Module "deployment.OASExtention-war.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator._resolveIntrospector(MapperConfigurator.java:169) [jackson-jaxrs-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator._resolveIntrospectors(MapperConfigurator.java:144) [jackson-jaxrs-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator._setAnnotations(MapperConfigurator.java:131) [jackson-jaxrs-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator.getDefaultMapper(MapperConfigurator.java:70) [jackson-jaxrs-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.locateMapper(JacksonJsonProvider.java:609) [jackson-jaxrs-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:404) [jackson-jaxrs-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:106) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.8.Final-redhat-3.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.read(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:63) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.8.Final-redhat-3.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:109) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.8.Final-redhat-3.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:169) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.8.Final-redhat-3.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:136) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.8.Final-redhat-3.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:159) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.8.Final-redhat-3.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:269) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.8.Final-redhat-3.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:227) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.8.Final-redhat-3.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:216) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.8.Final-redhat-3.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:542) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.8.Final-redhat-3.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.8.Final-redhat-3.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:126) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.8.Final-redhat-3.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.8.Final-redhat-3.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.8.Final-redhat-3.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.8.Final-redhat-3.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_73]
```

Server returns status code 500. Note that this happens on first call to the service. On second call rest service works as expected.

My Function Looks like this

```
@POST
@Path("matterNote")
@Consumes("application/json") 
@Produces("application/json")
public String matterNoteFunction(JSONObject json) throws IOException{ return "bla"; }
```

I am really confused and and waiting for any suggestions.

EDIT:

I tried to add [Download jackson-xc.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjacksonxcjar.htm) but got followin exception (on first call to a service):

```
java.lang.VerifyError: class org.codehaus.jackson.xc.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector overrides final method findDeserializer.(Lorg/codehaus/jackson/map/introspect/Annotated;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:361)
    org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482)
    org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:277)
    org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:92)
    org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:568)
    org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134)
    org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator._resolveIntrospector(MapperConfigurator.java:169)
    org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator._resolveIntrospectors(MapperConfigurator.java:144)
    org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator._setAnnotations(MapperConfigurator.java:131)
    org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator.getDefaultMapper(MapperConfigurator.java:70)
    org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.locateMapper(JacksonJsonProvider.java:609)
    org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:404)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:106)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.read(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:63)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:109)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:169)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:136)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:159)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:269)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:227)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:216)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:542)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:126)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue following way: In my application I am using json-lib.jar which needs other dependencies to be presented in classpath to function properly. I removed old dependencies, then added following ones:

[image]

And the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

I think XC Jackson lib is optional and The XC package allows you to use Xml Annotations (JAXB) in addition to the Jackson Annotations for mapping classes unless you need JAXB support just ignore the issue.

Comment: Thank you for response i solved this issue. I am going to post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had a same issue (using Spring) with:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

but when I extend provider definition in the beans.xml by mapper definition:

```
<jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider">
            <property name="mapper" ref="jacksonMapper" />
        </bean>
</jaxrs:providers>
<bean id="jacksonMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper" />
```

it started to work without initial exception.