# JaxbAnnotationIntrospector ClassNotFound on first call

Tags: java, rest, jackson

if I start my backend the first call to the rest service throws the following exception:

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/enoMiMa].[de.nobiscum.ncwheel.rest.JaxRsActivator]] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet de.nobiscum.ncwheel.rest.JaxRsActivator threw exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.xc.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector from [Module "deployment.enoMiMa.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator._resolveIntrospector(MapperConfigurator.java:171) [jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:1.9.13]
        at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator._resolveIntrospectors(MapperConfigurator.java:146) [jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:1.9.13]
        at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator._setAnnotations(MapperConfigurator.java:133) [jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:1.9.13]
        at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator.getDefaultMapper(MapperConfigurator.java:70) [jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:1.9.13]
        at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.locateMapper(JacksonJsonProvider.java:649) [jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:1.9.13]
        at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.writeTo(JacksonJsonProvider.java:501) [jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:1.9.13]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyWriterContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyWriterContextImpl.java:117) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.JacksonJsonpInterceptor.write(JacksonJsonpInterceptor.java:112) [resteasy-jackson-provider-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyWriterContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyWriterContextImpl.java:123) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPEncodingInterceptor.write(GZIPEncodingInterceptor.java:104) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyWriterContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyWriterContextImpl.java:123) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponse.writeTo(ServerResponse.java:250) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeJaxrsResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:616) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:528) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:126) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.omnifaces.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:115) [omnifaces-1.7.jar:1.7]
        at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:77) [omnifaces-1.7.jar:1.7]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractAuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke(AbstractAuthenticatedActionsValve.java:67) [keycloak-tomcat-core-adapter-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:499) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.invoke(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:181) [keycloak-tomcat-core-adapter-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_232]
```

I already tried to use different versions of of my jackson libraries but nothing helped.

These are my dependencies for jackson:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
```

My JaxRsActivator class looks like this:

```
@Startup
@ApplicationPath("/api/v1")
public class JaxRsActivator extends Application {
    /* class body intentionally left blank */
}
```

I am a beginner and this is my first question on stackoverflow, so please be forgiven.
I will add more information if needed.

Edit:

I tried to extend my beans with the provider definition like [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException On first call of the rest Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38789525/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-on-first-call-of-the-rest-service) here. But it didn't solve my problem. It could be that I made an mistake. My Bean.xml looks like this at the moment (without the solution from the other post):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
    <interceptors>
        <class>de.nobiscum.ncwheel.monitoring.PerformanceAuditor</class>
    </interceptors>
</beans>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException On first call of the rest Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38789525/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-on-first-call-of-the-rest-service)

Comment: No, i am not using json-lib.jar.

Comment: You may not be using the same library, but the solution is probably the same: you are missing one or more dependencies somewhere.

Comment: How can i check which dependencies im missing or which one i need?